# Rejoin the groups i had created on a previous Whatsapp account

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have recently changed my phone number, and so I had to delete my older account on WhatsApp.
Can I rejoin the groups that I had created before deleting the account? Would they still be in existence?

Comment: Probably not, now that your account is gone. PS: Whatsapp's approach to easy registering (using the phone no. as id and auth) is fundamentally broken, they have (or at least recently had) very bad security problems and other nasty workarounds/limitations: http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/20971798 (*Also, please do not swap SIM cards or phones frequently, or you will no longer be able to pass the verification process. Read this article for more information.*)

Comment: So they wont be in existence at all? I was under the assumption that the first person i had added to that group would have the admin rights for it.

Comment: Oh, I'm not that sure. Would you mind to try it? And post your findings here?

Comment: My assumption was correct. The groups are still in existence with the first person added being the new administrator.

Comment: Nice find! Would you mind to add this as an answer?

Comment: This seems to be completely external to Android.

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation, I found out that the older groups are still in existence and the first person I had added in each of them, when they were created, became the admin of the groups. I had to ask them to add me back to the group.